# beautifulsoup not parsing all links in html page

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have created this small program to load the url from file and parse the data but when I am running this program beautifulsoap is not parsing the links correctly. Although I have verified that if I put the url individually from a file in the program and run it I get the data I need.

problem with program using url from file :

```
with open('software.txt', 'r') as s:
for line in s:
    source = requests.get(line).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    softs = []
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        softs.append(link.get('href'))
        print(softs)
```

The above program runs when I put use it as below :-

```
source = requests.get('google.com').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    softs = []
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        softs.append(link.get('href'))
        print(softs)
```

Answer (score 0):

put the `softs = []` outside the loop or it will be overwritten

```
softs = []
with open('software.txt', 'r') as s:
    for line in s:
        source = requests.get(line).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

        for link in soup.find_all('a'):
            softs.append(link.get('href'))

print(softs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the full URL for each one:
example: http://www.google.com or https://stackoverflow.com/

Maybe you can add the error to your question for more clarity.

```
with open('software.txt', 'r') as s:
    for line in s:
        source = requests.get(line).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
        softs = []
        for link in soup.find_all('a'):
            softs.append(link.get('href'))
            print(softs)
```

software.txt looks like below:

[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmMFw.png)

Comment: It works for me as well and there are no errors but bs is not parsing full page with the code above.